# Tunnel a static IP that is assigned to a VPS to home router

Tags: networking, router, tunnel, vps

I currently have a VPS with a single, static IP. Would the following scenario be possible if I bought a second static IP?

Suppose IP A on eth0:0 is **1.2.3.4** and static IP B on eth0:1 is **5.6.7.8**.
I want to route all traffic going to IP A to my home router, without using server-side NAT. I think of establishing a GRE tunnel (secured with IPsec) between my home router and IP B. The incoming IP packets at IP A would then need to be passed inside the tunnel. I think a diagram should make this more clear:
[image: network diagram]
Usually, this would be a clear case of using a Site-to-Site-VPN and using NAT on the VPS, but I actually *do not want to use NAT server-side*. Instead, I want my home router to do srcnat on the outgoing and dstnat on specific incoming traffic. The VPS should only "pass through" the in- and outgoing IP packets.

I imagine the packet flow as following:

1. Host inside LAN 192.168.100.0/24 wants to send a packet to, say, 8.8.8.8
2. Home router scrnats this to the static IP A (1.2.3.4)
3. packet goes through gre1 and enters the VPS
4. VPS forwards the packet through eth0:0, leaving the source IP field unmodified
5. reply from 8.8.8.8 arrives at VPS with destination IP 1.2.3.4
6. VPS takes the packet and puts it into gre1, without doing any NAT
7. home router processes the packet and checks if it is a established or related connection and forwards it to the corresponding LAN client.

I guess I could simply add another IP on the gre1 interface on my router, namely 1.2.3.4, so it would 1) accept IP packets with this destination value and 2) send outgoing packets with that IP instead of the tunnel IP (10.0.0.2)?

Put shortly, I simply want all packets arriving at eth0:0 to arrive unmodified at gre1 on my home router. Would this be possible in the described way?

BTW, I'm using a Mikrotik router at home, if that is of any additional information.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Step 6 is the difficult one, because the destination IP is the interface IP so the routing decision would be to not route. And because the NAT is done else where....  In this scenario, all packets that arrive on 1.2.3.4 would need to be forced into the gre tunnel, so you'd need iptables shenanigans to get it to work.  You say you don't want to NAT on the server - is this because you can't?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I could NAT on the server, but would prefer to do it at my home router, because a) my Mikrotik router would give me a bit more control (or at least make the configuration more easy than just using the CLI server-side) and b) I simply wanted to try it :-) Besides using iptables -- would perhaps a bridge containing my eth and a layer 2 link, e.g. via L2TP, be feasible? So that all ethernet frames are relayed into the L2TP tunnel?

Comment: Hmm, bridge the eth0:0  and tun0 interfaces?  Or eth0:1?  What is the underlying thing you are trying to solve, perhaps there is another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, stop thinking of eth0 and eth0:1 as separate interfaces. Stop *drawing* them as separate interfaces. They're not. You have one eth0 interface with two IP addresses on it – the rest is an illusion which Linux plays on old tools like *ifconfig*.

---

With that out of the way, this is quite simple on the server side.

1. To configure this on your server, start by *removing* the 5.6.7.8 address from eth0. You don't want the server to think those packets belong to it and consume them; you want it to act as a pure router, and having a routed address assigned to a local interface is exactly what a router doesn't need.

   ```
   ip addr del 5.6.7.8/x dev eth0
   ```
2. Now add a static route for the address over your tunnel:

   ```
   ip route add 5.6.7.8/32 dev gre1
   ```
3. That's it (almost). The only remaining complication is that the server still needs to answer ARP queries for this address coming from your hosting company's local gateway. For that you need the *proxy-ARP* feature:

   ```
   ip neigh add proxy 5.6.7.8 dev eth0
   ```

   This enables proxy-ARP for *one* address. Do not use `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp=1` to enable it globally; that would cause proxy-ARP responses for everything that your server has a route for, which may be convenient in some cases but unnecessary in this case.

   *(As a side note, userspace [parpd](https://github.com/rsmarples/parpd) or [ndppd](https://github.com/DanielAdolfsson/ndppd) may be easier to understand than kernel-based proxy-ARP/NDP.)*

The more complex configuration might be needed on the *client* router, as it has to choose between two default gateways (direct route versus GRE) depending on the source IP address.

Fortunately, Mikrotik RouterOS has the Linux policy-routing feature for *at least* IPv4 (but still not for IPv6), so you can follow the widespread Linux `ip rule` instructions and map them 1:1 to RouterOS commands. In short:

1. Add a default route over GRE tunnel to a different routing <del>table</del> mark (RouterOS calls it 'routing mark'):

   ```
   /ip route add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=gre0 routing-mark="tunnelled"
   ```
2. Add a policy rule to choose this routing <del>mark</del> table (RouterOS...) for packets from this source address:

   ```
   /ip rule add src-address=5.6.7.8/32 table="tunnelled"
   ```

---

A comment mentions bridging. That won't work for two reasons.

GRE is a Layer3 tunnel that doesn't transport Ethernet-like headers and is therefore not bridgeable. There are Layer2 variants of it, such as Linux gretap and Mikrotik eoip – unfortuntely these are mutually incompatible despite both being GRE-based.

The comment actually mentions *tun*, perhaps under the assumption that the tunnel is OpenVPN (GRE isn't OpenVPN), but tun is also a Layer3 interface. Now there is a Layer2 version – *tap* interface – and Linux OpenVPN can in fact be configured to use it and be a Layer2 VPN... but the RouterOS OpenVPN implementation doesn't support that mode anyway.

Moreover, because eth0:1 *is not* a separate interface, it cannot be bridged without also bridging eth0 itself. Could a *macvlan* virtual interface be created off eth0 and then bridged with a tunnel? Not sure. It would probably be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I'm aware that this is a 2-year-old question. No, I don't really care. If I'm unable to write a good answer for in-date questions these days, at least I'll write an out-of-date one.